# On a sum of infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

[image]

[image]

(Second image is answer) Could somebody show how exactly the last line is derived? **and why are the indices on the partial sums 1 and 3?** **Why not some other numbers? I really don't understand..**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $ \frac{1}{2} \sum^m_{n=2} \frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{2} \sum^m_{n=2} \frac{1}{n+1} $.

For the first sum, assume that $ p = n - 1 $ and after replacing it, you get $ \frac{1}{2} \sum^{m-1}_{p=1} \frac{1}{p} $. For instance, for the lower bound of the first sum you have $ n = 2 $. After replacing $ p $, you obtain $ p + 1 = 2 \leftrightarrow p = 1 $.

For the second sum, assume that $ q = n + 1 $ and after replacing it on the sum, you get $ \frac{1}{2} \sum^{m+1}_{q=3} \frac{1}{q} $.

Comment: Ok, thank you, i got it for the lower indices. I assume that we put m-1 and m+1 because we want the same amount (M) of numbers summed, so because we go form 2 to 1 we put m-1 and same for m+1?

Comment: Yes! In the first sum the lower bound is $  n = 2 $. The upper bound is $ n = m $. So, after replacing $p$, you obtain $ p + 1 = m \leftrightarrow p = m - 1$

Answer (score 2):

Expand it out and you'll see all the terms cancel out except for the first $2$ in the first sum and the last $2$ in the second sum.

Comment: Ok, I got the last line when I did what you said. But why exactly do we decide to put those 2 indices there. Why not 2 and 5? or some other numbers. Is there something i'm missing?

Comment: The answer is correct and easy to follow. Why was there a downvote?